# Is there any possible way to avoid repetitive code?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to remove the repetitive code by providing method as parameter in javascript? Below is the code.

```
var toastrService = function (toastr) {
  var _toastrService = this;

  _toastrService.success =function(message,title) {
      toastr.success(message,title);
  }

  _toastrService.info =function(message,title) {
      toastr.info(message,title);
  }

  _toastrService.error =function(message,title) {
      toastr.error(message,title);
  }

  _toastrService.warning =function(message,title) {
      toastr.warning(message,title);
  }

  _toastrService.success =function(message,title) {
      toastr.success(message,title);
  }

}
```

Comment: Why do any of this at all…?

Comment: why not add a third parameter for the target?

Comment: Your `toastrService` has a very low value, just use directly `toastr` no?

Comment: @sjahan: Until the day they want to switch to a different implementation - let's say "toasterUltra". They will have to change only one file. When using toaster directly you will have to change every file that uses it. So what you call low value, is actually called encapsulation and a good thing.

Comment: @DanieleTorino I agree and I disagree :) If something changes, the code will have to change anyway. The risk of this change must be assessed to determine if this is actually valuable. For example, you could also change the proxy at one point, so why not protecting it by proxying the proxy, etc. Encapsulation (as a lot of things) must not be dogmatic, but pragmatic.

Comment: @sjahan: Oh yes, absolutely. But in my experience encapsulating common functionality like logging or notification libraries is very useful especially in bigger projects. The metric I use is usually: How often do I use this, in how many classes? How likely is the implementation going to change? And last but not least: "I have refactored this what feels like tenth time now... maybe I should encapsulate it."

Comment: `success` is a good thing, but do you really need it twice..?

Comment: @Daniele If and when you want to substitute the toaster with something else, *then* you can introduce this kind of code without altering anything. For all intents and purposes, you are using `toastr` directly here. If and when you want to replace it, just write a wrapper exactly like this around your new toaster and transparently replace `toastrService`, keeping exactly the same API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over an array of property strings:

```
['success', 'info', 'error', 'warning', 'success'].forEach((prop) => {
  _toastrService[prop] = function(message, title) {
    toastr[prop](message, title);
  };
});
```

If you don't need to strip excess function arguments, you can trim it down to:

```
['success', 'info', 'error', 'warning', 'success'].forEach((prop) => {
  _toastrService[prop] = toastr[prop].bind(toastr);
});
```

If the functions don't need a `this` of `toastr`, then you can leave out the `.bind` and just assign the plain function:

```
_toastrService[prop] = toastr[prop]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a global property injectable, simply declare it as an AngularJS value:

```
angular.module("app",[]).value("toastrService", toastr);
```

Then inject it where needed:

```
app.controller("ctrl", function (toastrService) {
    toastrService.info("Title","Message");
});
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS module type Reference - value](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#value)